# Bug in vector of list

Tags: c++, debugging

I am designing my HashSet in c++. I took vector of lists to hash the keys.

```
class MyHashSet {
public:
    vector<list<int>>val;
    MyHashSet() {
        val.resize(10000);
    }
    
    void add(int key) {
        
        val[key%10000].push_back(key);
    }
    
    void remove(int key) {
        auto lst=val[key%10000];
        
        for(auto i=lst.begin();i!=lst.end();i++)
          if(*i==key){lst.erase(i);return;}
       
        
    }
    
    bool contains(int key) {
        auto lst=val[key%10000];
        
        for(auto i=lst.begin();i!=lst.end();i++) if(*i==key)return true;
        
                return false;
        
    }
};
```

Doing

```
MyHashSet a;
a.add(2);
a.remove(2);
cout<<a.contains(2)//it returns true somehow.
```

the function returns true as if `2` a was not removed. I cannot figure out what's wrong with the code.

Comment: What is `Solution`? Create a [mcve]

Comment: I have edited it to MyHashSet

Answer (score 2):

`auto lst=val[key%10000];` is a copy of the list. You modify the copy, and that copy ceases to exist at the end of the function.

Aside: you don't need to manually search for the element, there is `std::list::remove`

```
void remove(int key) {
    val[key%10000].remove(key);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> the function returns true as if 2 a was not removed.

That's because you don't remove it (at least not from the list stored at `val[key%10000]`). `auto lst=val[key%10000];` creates a copy of the list stored at `val[key%10000]` and you remove the element from that copy.

You would need to store it as a reference `auto &lst=val[key%10000];`